# Bind attribute SAML AD and Cognito User with the type is list in SAML

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0

i am new in AWS Cognito.

I configure Cognito with Entra ID how IdP using SAML protocol. I can connect successful both services and I can map attributes between SAML and cognito user group. The problem is that 1 attribute in SAML is a list and Cognito only can proccess Number or String.

I can match attributes?

Cognito attributes:

[image]

Part of xml generate from Entra Id:

[image]

Finally, part of generate jwt for cognito where only see a one group
[image]

Cognito only allow this options:

[image]

Is it possible for cognito to accept a list?

Thanks

Comment: I can read tihs in aws doc: When IdP attributes contain multiple values, Amazon Cognito flattens all values into a single space-delimited string and URL form-encodes the values containing non-alphanumeric characters (excluding the ‘.’, ‘-’, ‘*’, and ‘_’ characters). You must decode and parse the individual values before you use them in your app. But dont work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this works.
[image]

Needs close this question!